# Create custom tool for kendo editor angular mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-editor

I want to add custom tool in kendo editor.
It is pretty good in jQuery method via directive, But have problem with model binding.

It seems I have to use angular method like this:

```
<textarea naccordion id="htmleditor" ng-model="Model._Active.Paragraph" class="editor" k-options="accordion" k-encoded="false" kendo-editor k-tools="['fontName','bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','fontSize','justifyLeft','justifyCenter','justifyRight','justifyFull','foreColor','insertUnorderedList','insertOrderedList','indent','outdent','createLink','unlink','insertImage','cleanFormatting','backColor','viewHtml','formatting']"></textarea>
```

So, I put my k-options code in controller:

```
        $scope.accordion = {
        tools:
            {
                name: "accordion",
                tooltip: "Accordion items",
                exec: function (e) {
                    var editor = $(this).data("kendoEditor");
                    editor.exec("inserthtml", {
                        value: "<accordion close-others='true'><accordion-group is-open='Model._openSettings'><accordion-heading>[Title]</accordion-heading><br>[Text]</accordion-group></accordion>"
                    });
                }
            }

    };
```

It is not work.
I do not know what is accordion scope is right or no?
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

tools needs to be an array:

```
 $scope.accordion = {
    tools:[
      {
       name: "accordion",
            tooltip: "Accordion items",
            exec: function (e) {
                var editor = $(this).data("kendoEditor");
                editor.exec("inserthtml", {
                    value: "<accordion close-others='true'><accordion-group is-open='Model._openSettings'><accordion-heading>[Title]</accordion-heading><br>[Text]</accordion-group></accordion>"
                });
            }
      }
    ]

};
```